# Join from two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a doubt where trying to join two tables by a previous search. I've looked several solutions and read some chapters in a mysql book but I think I'm pretty close to the right answer but still not get it

I have this table "userprocess":

```
idProcess          username         state
------------------------------------------
1                  blisssing        3
2                  enriquecalvera   1
2                  africabaluja     2
1                  enriquecalvera   3
2                  blisssing        1
```

The primery key for this table is the union of idProceso+username.

I have this other table "user":

```
index      username        pass            active      tipeUser     .... so on
-----------------------------------------------------------------   ----
1          blisssing       6OiZVVUPi3LDE   1           user
2          carmen          6OOtfrXB2Nu5.   1           user 
3          consuelo        6OgdhVSkr1VDs   1           user
4          africabaluja    6OoPtGjWMQARE   1           user
5          enriquecalvera  6O6tvHg.122uQ   1           user
```

The thing is I want to show the join of the two tables but with a search within the first table. If I run this query

```
SELECT username FROM userprocess where idProcess='1' ORDER BY state
```

I get this:

```
username
---------
blisssing
enriquecalvera
```

which is what I am looking for, but I want to show all the fields in the "user" table for those usernames ordered by idProceso. So I run this other query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  user u,
  userprocess p
WHERE
  u.username=p.username
  AND u.username IN (
    SELECT username 
    FROM userprocess 
    where idProcess='1'
    ORDER BY username
) ORDER BY p.state
```

I got this:

```
username        pass           active   tipeUser   idProcess    state
----------------------------------------------------------------------
blisssing       6Od3nSkfOiwlg  1        user       2            1 
enriquecalvera  6Oc9usiDEk51U  1        user       2            1
enriquecalvera  6Oc9usiDEk51U  1        user       1            3
blisssing       6Od3nSkfOiwlg  1        user       2            3
```

But this is not what I want I just want the same two results as in the previous query but with all the columns of the result of joining the two tables..

I know there is a lot of questions like this, but I have tried a lot of things and still not having the desire result..

What am I missing?

thank you, if you have any qestion or doubt just ask :)

Comment: Which values do you want in the columns?  There is a reason why you get four rows.  You should edit your question with the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing multiple results is because you're joining on just the username, but of course the userprocess table has 2 rows where `username = enriquecalvera`. Your subquery is correctly only returning the 1 row you're interested in (where `idprocess = 1`) but as your join is seperate to this, and therefore doesn't include the `idprocess = 1` condition, you're getting both rows back.

You should just do this in one step with a join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  user u
INNER JOIN userprocess p on u.username=p.username and p.idProcess='1'
ORDER BY p.state
```

Comment: Your answer was correct! thank you so much, you just had an error on the query -> the table userprocess is the one with the column idProcess so it would be p.idProcess (I cannot edit it because its less than 6 characters). Thank you very much!